# Updating UI while running task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invoke

I have the following code:

```
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = Results.Count;

        foreach (MyClass cls in Results)
        {                
              progressBar1.Value += 1;

              // Go to DB and get large quantity of data
              cls.GetHistoryData();

        }
```

What I’d like to do is shift the processing to another thread so that progressBar1 updates correctly.  I’ve found an [article](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2008/08/c-threading-update-progress-bar.html) that implies that I should be able to use the Invoke method on the progress bar, but there doesn’t appear to be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind the progressbar to a data property you do not need to switch the thread context manually. The WPF binding engine will do this automatically for you.

```
<ProgressBar Value={Binding Progress} />
```

And then in your thread:

```
foreach (MyClass cls in Results)
{                
      // databinding will automatically marshal to UI thread
      this.Progress++;
      cls.GetHistoryData();
}
```

In most cases this is much cleaner and less error prone than marshalling on your own using [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: This looks like the ideal solution.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.  I'm making an assumption that Progress would need to be set-up as a class level variable (otherwise it doesn't recognise it), is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: It depends on you your setup. You could add a property to your UserControl/Window and bind to it just like in this post: http://goo.gl/ZMcnp
Or more ideally, if you go with MVVM (wich makes a lot things much easier!) you would have a DataTemplate for your ProgressDialogViewModel class wich has a CurrentProgress property and othet things like a Message and Tiltle property. In you DataTemplate you bind against those properties.

Comment: +1 - Best solution. However instead of implementing a dependency property for "Progress" I would use INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I wasn't mentioning a dependency property anywhere. I too prefery INPC

Answer (score 2):

You should check [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. It supports progress and handles communication between threads properly.

Answer (score 0):

You would start a new thread as such:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(methodnametocall);
   t1.start();

void methodnametocall()
{
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
   {

        control to update;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
progressBar1.Maximum = Results.Count;

foreach (MyClass cls in Results)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
             {
                 progressBar1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                     (Action) (() => progressBar1.Value += 1));
                 cls.GetHistoryData();
             });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The article you link to is a winforms example, but you are making a WPF application. In your case, you should look into using the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) class instead, that you get through the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property of the control.